# How to add 2 onclick event methods for a single element which class has dynamically change on the first click event method on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

On this click event, it changes the clicked elements class from 'fa-pencil-square-o' to 'fa-floppy-o'.

```
$("i.fa.fa-pencil-square-o").click(function () {
    var parentid = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    var parent = $('tr#' + parentid);

    var rtn;
    var rtd;

    if (parent.find('td:nth-child(4)').text() == 'No') {

        rtn = parent.find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
        rtd = parent.find('td:nth-child(3)').text();

        parent.find('td:nth-child(2)').empty();
        parent.find('td:nth-child(3)').empty();

        //changes class here
        parent.find('td:nth-child(5)').empty();
        parent.find('td:nth-child(5)').append('<i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>');


        parent.find('td:nth-child(2)').append('<input type="text" id="rtName" />');
        parent.find('td:nth-child(3)').append('<input type="text" id="rtDescription" />');

        $(parent).find('input#rtName').val(rtn);
        $(parent).find('input#rtDescription').val(rtd);
    }

});
```

When the class of the same clicked element changes to 'fa-floppy-o' I wanted this click event to take effect but it doesn't and still invokes the first click event above.

```
    $('.fa-floppy-o').click(function () {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var rtn = parent.find('input#rtName');
    var rtd = parent.find('input#rtDescription');

    $.ajax({
        url: '/editRoomType',
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            roomTypeID: parent.attr('id'),
            roomTypeName: rtn.val(),
            roomTypeDescription: rtd.val()
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.isSuccessful) {
                $('#msgdiv').css("display", "inline");
                $('#msg').empty();
                $('#msgdiv').removeClass('alert-danger');
                $('#msgdiv').addClass('alert-success');
                $.each(data.Message, function (key, value) {
                    $('#msg').append(value + '<br />')
                })
                $('.table-details tbody').empty();
                parent.find('td:nth-child(5)').empty();
                parent.find('td:nth-child(5)').append('<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
                getRoomType();

            } else {
                $('#msgdiv').css("display", "inline");
                $('#msg').empty();
                $('#msgdiv').removeClass('alert-success');
                $('#msgdiv').addClass('alert-danger');
                $.each(data.Message, function (key, value) {
                    $('#msg').append(value + '<br />')
                })
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error accounts')
        }
    });

});
```

What I basically want to accomplish is for the elements' on click event function to change when the class of the element changes. But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the listener directly to the element with the provided class, instead add the listener to a parent element using jQuery's `on()` event delegation, and provide the class of the clicked element as the second parameter.  Even `document` works.

This is the definition of the jQuery `on()` event handler:

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

Change this line:

```
$("i.fa.fa-pencil-square-o").click(function () {
```

to this:

```
$(document).on("click", "i.fa.fa-pencil-square-o", function() {
```

And this line:

```
 $('.fa-floppy-o').click(function () {
```

to this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".fa-floppy-o", function() {
```

The reason being: jQuery adds those listeners once when the page loads.  Because it doesn't find anything with the class `.fa-floppy-o`, it doesn't add a listener.  This is true of renaming (re-classing) elements, and also elements dynamically generated by jQuery/Javascript after page load.

The event will bubble up from the element to the parent element and that parent element will check to see if the element has the selector provided in the second argument.

More on event bubbling:

> Direct and delegated events
>
> The majority of browser events bubble, or propagate, from the deepest,
>   innermost element (the event target) in the document where they occur
>   all the way up to the body and the document element.
>
> ...
>
> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as
>   delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on
>   the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that
>   match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up
>   to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to
>   outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that
>   path matching the selector.

Here's documentation for the `on()` function in jQuery:  http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I will try this solution out when I get home.

Comment: Any luck with this solution?